# Can't push commit to github because it's too big

Tags: git, github

I;ve been making my own little game in Unity. For version control, I'm using Github. Yesterday, I tried to push my changes and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYlOd.jpg) appeared. As far as I know, the commit was too big.
I tried to use github lfs but it seems like it's not working at all. Just to clarify some things, this is what I tried:

```
git lfs install<br>
git lfs track 'path/to/my/project/.'<br>
git add .<br>
git commit -m "text"<br>
git push<br>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to push big commits?

Answer (score 0):

Github restricts filesize per their [disk quota](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/).

While Git LFS is the recommended alternative, you still need to pay for file storage via [LFS data packs](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/). Github does not provided unlimited storage space for free.